# same addin working in different instances of excel

Tags: excel, vba

the present addin works fine in the first instance of excel. However when sap open a second instance of excel (export of the data to an excel-file) the working addin doesn't show and isn't active.
So I would like to get a working addin (already shown in ribbon) in any other extra instance of excel.
tia

Answer (score 1):

When Excel is activated by automation, the add-ind don't load automatically. You  might need to find a way to get SAP to run some extra code to set `.Installed = true` after starting Excel.

Comment: That will be very hard to achieve from the tech guys. Thank you for the answer. Still hoping on another way.